# Django - Display specific attribute of object in <Select> in template

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have the following Python models:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    senha = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    meta = models.ManyToManyField('meta', through='Usuario_meta')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'id: {self.id} - login: {self.login} - senha: {self.senha}'

class Meta(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'id: {self.id} - senha: {self.tipo}'

class Usuario_meta(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meta = models.ForeignKey(Meta,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.DateField()
    valor = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Meta do usuário: {self.usuario} - meta:{self.meta} - data:{self.data} - valor: {self.valor}'
```

The following view:

```
class UsuarioMetaCreate(CreateView):
    model = Usuario_meta
    template_name = 'lancamento_meta_cadastro.html'
    fields = '__all__'
```

The following template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Which displays the following:
[image]

I would like to show, in the "usuario" select, only the attribute "login". Apparently, it calls the '**str**()' and displays all the fields. Is there a way to show only a specific attribute while using CreateView and without modifying the '**str**()' method?

I have already tried using

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.usuario.login}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

But it doesn't display anything

Comment: override `__str__` before passing as `model` attribute in `UsuarioMetaCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Define a function just like the original `__str__` with deferent name

```py
def custom_usuario_str(obj):
    return f"{obj.senha}"
```

before passing the model to `UsuarioMetaCreate` we override the original `__str__`

so when it's called in drop down, `custom_usuario_str` will be triggered instead!

```py
class UsuarioMetaCreate(CreateView):
    model = override_model_str(Usuario)
    template_name = 'lancamento_meta_cadastro.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    @staticmethod
    def override_model_str(model):
        model.__str__ = custom_usuario_str
        return Usuario
```